# Cylinder texturing : how to make side and edge connected?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, edges, uv-image-editor

I want to apply a texture seamlessly from the top to the sides. How can I do this? Currently there's a visible seam between the top and the sides.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply unwrap the top and side of your cylinder together it will work fine as it will keep the sides connected to the top. It won't work for the bottom though, imagine wrapping a flat square drawing around a cylinder, it won't work for the bottom (or it will be very deformed).

[image]

If you want to have the texture on the bottom, maybe choose this solution, first select this edge and mark seam, then unwrap, it will extend the image on the bottom:

[image]

Then you can paint the center with the *Stencil* in order to make the joint (I'm not sure that it will work fine with the texture you show though):

[image]

Comment: Merci moonboots ! (ps: je te suis sur youtube, tes vidéos sont super pratiques !)

Comment: there's any way to do it for the bottom to ?

Comment: ah merci beaucoup  ;)

Comment: For the bottom the only trick I see is to paint with the Stencil in order to make the joint with the side, but it won't be easy though

Comment: But I have an idea to make it simpler, wait for my edit